# How to replace '<p>' with '<li>' in an array in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Let's say I have this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var array = $.makeArray($('p'));
   $(array).appendTo(document.body);
   });
});
```

---

```
<p>how</p>
<p>are</p>
<p>you</p>
<p>baby?</p>
```

If I want to replace `<p>` with `<li>` and expected output is ...

```
<li>how</li>
<li>are</li>
<li>you</li>
<li>baby?</li>
```

What should I do? Thanks in advance!

Comment: you probably also want an <ul> around that?

Comment: No I don't. Just need simple one and I've got answer :)

Comment: just a bunch of <li> elements is invalid html/xhtml. The "works for me" scenario might hurt in the future

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$("p").each(function () {
     $(this).replaceWith("<li>" + $(this).html() + "</li>");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick and dirty solution, but if you give me more details as far as what you are trying to do we might be able to come up with a better one.

```
$('p').each(function(){$(this).replaceWith('<li>'+$(this).html()+'</li>')})
```

Comment: `$(this).text()` removes the inner html from the `<p>` tags. `.html()` is better