# Replacing innercontent in a html using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HERE IS PSEUDO CODE

```
var content = $('.getcontent').html();
print content
"<p>one</p>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<a>ok<a><br>1"
 replace.content(li with p)
```

output:

```
print content 
  "<p>one</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <a>ok</a><br>1"
```

How can i do that to get my results?

Comment: try searching before posting, you can get the basic idea here:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543617/how-to-replace-p-with-li-in-an-array-in-jquery

Comment: other tags are also present here? Will it work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [`.replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/#replaceWith-function) along with its `receiver function` to accomplish your task,

```
$('.getcontent').find('li').replaceWith(function(_,content){
  return '<p>' + content + '</p>';
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/czQAL/1/)

**Note:** I am not fully aware of your context, Anyway this code would make an invalid HTML.

Comment: what about the other tags? <a> <br>

Comment: @SomPathak Hey, you did not mention that in the question initially..? Just now you added the additional informations.. Anyway your new html structure wont cause any odd behaviors. since we have selected the li elements particularly.